# Class methods in VBA / VB

Tags: excel, vba

When trying to use a class in VBA I keep getting a subscript out of range error and could use some help here!

This is the class -

```
Option Explicit
Private buildWs As String
Public Property Get affBuild() As String
    affBuild = buildWs
End Property

Public Property Let affBuild(value As String)
    buildWs = affBuild
End Property

Public Function activate()
    Sheets(buildWs).activate
End Function
```

This is the call -

```
Sub SetWs()
    Dim current As CBuildSheet
    Set current = New CBuildSheet
    current.affBuild = "Resource Entry"
    current.activate
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is wrong...

```
Public Property Let affBuild(value As String)
  buildWs = affBuild
End Property
```

and should be...

```
Public Property Let affBuild(value As String)
  buildWs = value
End Property
```

see . http://ramblings.mcpher.com/Home/excelquirks/snippets/classes for getting started with classes.

Bruce

Answer (score 4):

Your `Let` method should be using the `value` parameter:

```
Public Property Let affBuild(value As String)
    buildWs = value
End Property
```

Your `Public Function activate()` is not returning any value.

Perhaps, you should use `Public Sub activate()`.

Comment: Thanks - I don't know how I missed that value part.